# Using auto layout to enforce UIView in UITableView fill the screen

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiview, autolayout, ios8

I am attempting to add a background view to my table that should stretch in size to always fill the frame of the table upon rotation. To simplify the question, I'm just attempting to add a red `UIVIew` to the table view, and then use auto layout in order to ensure the red view will always fill the entire visible background. If I don't implement auto layout, upon rotation you can see the red no longer fills the visible area on screen. But when I do implement auto layout using the code below, the red view is no longer visible on screen. I just see the default table view `backgroundColor`. Why is that, what's wrong with my auto layout code?

```
UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:self.tableView.frame];
view.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
[self.tableView addSubview:view];
[self.tableView sendSubviewToBack:view];

[view setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
[self.tableView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:view
                                                                           attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
                                                                           relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                                              toItem:self.tableView
                                                                           attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
                                                                          multiplier:1
                                                                            constant:0]];
                [self.tableView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:view
                                                                           attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom
                                                                           relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                                              toItem:self.tableView
                                                                           attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom
                                                                          multiplier:1
                                                                            constant:0]];
                [self.tableView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:view
                                                                           attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading
                                                                           relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                                              toItem:self.tableView
                                                                           attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading
                                                                          multiplier:1
                                                                            constant:0]];
                [self.tableView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:view
                                                                           attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing
                                                                           relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                                              toItem:self.tableView
                                                                           attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing
                                                                          multiplier:1
                                                                            constant:0]];
```

Comment: I don't think there's anything worn with your auto layout code, it's just that table views don't play well with auto layout. What are you trying to accomplish with this code (why not just change the table's background color)?

Comment: @rdelmar I'm attempting to add a background view to the table, but it's not a solid color. To be precise, it's going to be a `UIVisualEffectview`. The red view demonstrates the setup without the complexity of getting that blur effect set up. I just need it to always fill the height/width of the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the backgroundView property to the table view. Just create your view with alloc init (no frame or constraints necessary) and set that view as the table view's background view,

```
    UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] init];
    view.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    self.tableView.backgroundView = view;
```

Unless your cells are clear, you won't see this view until you pull the view down or scroll it past the bottom.

Comment: Much easier! Thank you.